# ImageResizer (as standalone image server) and backend image sources

Tags: imageresizer

**Current Setup:** Large CMS that has an *"authoring"* server and multiple *"delivery"* servers. Both the authoring and delivery servers are Windows servers running 64-bit Apache. The Apache Web root is setup on each server exactly the same--points to a directory on a SAN. The delivery servers are load balanced via another Windows server running Apache. I just finished setting up the ImageResizer server as a standalone image server and wanted to see what the best approach to getting the ImageResizer server to access and thus serve up the images.

1. authoring server - a.site.com
2. delivery server - d.site.com
3. image server - i.site.com

So I guess the question is, what is the best way to allow the ImageResizer server access to the images that are part of a large CMS site? RemoteReader plugin? Setup the IIS site with the Web root as the same as the authoring and delivery servers? Any security issues with this approach? Any suggestions/alternate approaches?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the SAN is well-behaved, SMB2 or later, and low-latency, you could mount the directory as a virtual folder within the IIS root (which you might want to keep separate).

For performance, it would be best to disable FCNMode - http://imageresizing.net/docs/v3/docs/fcnmode - particularly if you have lots of directories in the SAN.

Alternatively, you could use RemoteReader and point it to your Apache web servers, although you'll sacrifice the ability to update existing files (RemoteReader perma-caches everything to make performance reasonable).

Comment: The SAN is very high performance, however the SAN shares are hosted on a clustered set of Windows Server 2012 **VMs**. We will have to do some performance testing to see how well the site does under load.

The site is rather larger, with over 500+ subsites and we would like to keep the image paths the same (except for the server/host part), so while I can see the benefit of using the virtual directory within the IIS site root, making the IIS site root the actual site itself is probably what we are going to go with.

Good call on the FCNMode... I will definitely disable that.